# My XPath is not working for all the scenario

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

I need to do assertion with the total of table and to do this when I am writing XPath for total in image table its not working for all the scenario. I know the reason because the table is dynamic so sometimes its have only 1 Image and sometime its have 5 Image so I am having difficulty to wrote x-path which works for all the scenario.

For the attached image I have written : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5zhQ.png)
WebElement totalElement  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="image_table"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]"));
its running fine but when the table size changes. it failed.

for reference the webpage design is as below,

```
***<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover display" id="image_table">
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-right">Total</td>
      <td class="text-center">1,650</td>
      <td class="text-center">19,936</td>
      <td class="text-center">21,586</td> (trying to write xpath for this total)
  </tr>***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try css:

```
#image_table>tr>td:last-of-type
```

It always defines the last element.

**Update** based on comment. This css selector is more robust:

```
#image_table tr:last-of-type>td:last-of-type
```

Comment: Element not found.

Comment: ok, then update html code in your question

Comment: It worked with .//*[@id='image_table']/tbody/tr[position()=last()]/td[4] , thank you for help

Comment: Ok, check updated answer. Your locator is still having small issues. It selects last tr, not last td.

Answer (score 0):

```
//td[contains(string(),"Total")]/following-sibling::td[last()]
```

find td that contains the text total and find the last following td

Comment: //tr[contains(string(),"Total")]/td[last()] I tried with this but getting 4matches.

Comment: which are for match

Comment: I have used same code as you mentioned and getting following results.   1)<td class="text-right">1,321</td> 2) <td class="text-right">1,321</td> 3)<td class="text-center">21,625</td> 4) <td class="text-right vid-downloads">42</td> from all the below I need 3rd one only with 21,625 value.

Comment: please add the full table  ,

Comment: update the question with full table , as per the table in the question the locator in the answer works

Comment: It worked with .//*[@id='image_table']/tbody/tr[position()=last()]/td[4] , thank you for help